# If BERT's [CLS] can be retrained for a variety of sentence classification objectives, what about [SEP]?

Tags: transformer-model, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

In BERT pretraining, the [CLS] token is embedded into the input of a classifier tasked with the Next Sentence Prediction task (or, in some BERT variants, with other tasks, such as ALBERT's Sentence Order Prediction); this helps in the pretraining of the entire transformer, and it also helps to make the [CLS] position readily available for retraining to other "sentence scale" tasks.

I wonder whether [SEP] could also be retrained in the same manner.
While [CLS] will probably be easier to retrain as the transformer is already trained to imbue its embedding with meaning from across the sentence, while [SEP] does not have these "connections" (one would assume), this might still work with sufficient fine-tuning.

With this one could retrain the same model for two different classification tasks,   one using [CLS] and one using [SEP].

Am I missing anything? 
Is there a reason why this would not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory it can give 'some' results so it would work (it's just a token), but the question is why you would want to that. These tokens have been pretrained for a specific purpose. I suppose that by 'retrain' you mean finetuning, so if you would finetune the SEP token suddenly as a classification token, I think you won't get good results because you are only fine-tuning one token in the whole language model for a task that it wasn't even pretrained for.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is entirely useless, because the `[CLS]` token is often fine-tuned on a completely different classification (or even regression) task, which still yields good results. I would agree that you might arguably need more fine-tuning data to make it work decently, but I don't see any reason why `[SEP]` couldn't be used instead... Another reason might be that `[SEP]` is currently treated completely differently in the output, but I could find no such indicator.

Comment: @dennlinger CLS is pretrained on the classification task, but SEP isn't. So if you then want to finetune CLS on one classification task and SEP on another, I don't think the performance will be similar since CLS was already used as 'pooled' output whereas SEP never served such purpose. I am not saying that it is useless or that it won't work, I just think that it won't make for a fair comparison between the two tokens.

Comment: Let's say I want to finetune the BERT model to perform two different classification tasks.
Would it be better to feed the result of [CLS] into two different classifiers, or have [CLS] finetuned to one task alone, and use [SEP] for the other (taking the above disadvantages of [SEP] into account?

Comment: @Lafayette I wouldn't bother trying anything funny with SEP. I'd just put two classification heads on top which use as input the CLS token or otherwise pooled output of the base model.